# RemoteApp performance issues in Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remoteapp

When editing or saving rather large ms office or pdf files (1MB+), it seems that the printerdriver recalculates the printing settings (area and so on) of the document which causes enough load to make the remoteapp freeze for around 10 seconds. Printers are being mapped into the session locally by each client.
When using existing TS printers, everthing works fine.
The Clients access the TS farm through a site2site vpn.

Since this is a very specific problem, im not looking for an immediate solution but some ideas/thoughts on this would help a lot.

Comment: Validate the print job final size in the spooler. An PDF on a 'not PS' printer will become huge. I seen 5mb file finished at 200mb when trying to print that to a printer without a PS's module. Use the 'print as an image' in acrobat as a workaround.